# Error session count quantity product in cart not working on Pluign WP Rocket

Tags: php, wordpress, session

My website use plugin WP ROCKET error not auto update count quantity product in cart mini on header top menu when add cart product
I have setting "Never cache this page" for page CART and it good very well.
But all page and post other then not count quantity product in cart
This is my code session count cart

```
function count_cart() {
  @session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
    $count = count($_SESSION['cart']).' SP';
  } else {
    $count = '0';
  }
  return $count;
}
```

Please help me fix code. Thanks

Comment: is the count remains 0?

Comment: default value 0 for cart empty, and i want each value create session when add cart is display the total quantity? It works well when not installed plugin wp rocket, but how to do it in wp rocket